# Find an array of values into a table

Tags: excel, vba, match

I'm actually facing a problem today. I'm trying to find a row in an Excel Table and return it, based on an entire array of values supposed to match the table

[image: the table.]

There's a table exemple, they always start with an ID Column that is missing from my Array.

[image: This listbox]
This listbox are the data that I'm getting in my array.

I'm actually using  a function that search for a perfect match of my array into a specified table. But I need to make it start on second columns of table.
Here's my function.

```vb
Function checkDuplicate(ws As Worksheet, valuesArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Long, z As Long
    Dim ar
    
    If ws.Name = "Interface" Or ws.Name = "Listes" Then Exit Function
    z = LBound(valuesArray)
    n = UBound(valuesArray) - z + 1
    With ws
        ar = .UsedRange.Columns(1).Resize(, n)
        For i = 1 To UBound(ar)
            j = 1
            Do
                If ar(i, j) <> valuesArray(j + z - 1) Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop While j <= n
            If j > n Then
                checkDuplicate = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Function
```

Any help would be higlhy appreciated, Thank.

Comment: You say "I'm trying to find a row in an Excel Table and return it". Where in your code you try returning a row/range? To except the first column from the used range you should use : `ar = .UsedRange.Columns(1).Resize(, n).Offset(,1)`, if you want resizing its **columns**.. Then, how to match `idEntreprise` which is a number with `Entreprises` which is a string? Is your `valuesArray` array 2D 1 based? `UBound(valuesArray)` returns the array number of rows. Why using it in resizing the `UsedRange` number of columns? I confess that I cannot understand too much from your question/code...

Comment: My bad, I'm kinda bad at expressing my need I've some difficulties with english `idEntreprise` is an integer and `Entreprises` is a corresponding string, but I'm getting back the ID with a function. I'll try to use Offset by the way thanks for your reply !

Comment: And what about the other logical strange aspects? Why using the array number of rows to resize the `UsedRange` number of columns? And what about **the row to be returned**? If you do not help us to understand your problem, nobody can help you in any way...

Comment: Actualy I'm using the numbers of row to create an Array which contains each rows as array so I can compare my initial array to all the existing records

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry. Maybe somebody else more patient will do it. i wish you success!

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your time I'm sorry for not making myself more intelligible.

Comment: If you are trying to match on multiple columns (if I'm understanding this right), you could `Join` the elements in your array into a string, and do the comparison on the joined string.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print checkDuplicate(ActiveSheet, Array("A", "B", "C", "D"))
End Sub

Function checkDuplicate(ws As Worksheet, valuesArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Long, z As Long
    Dim ar, col As Long, sz As Long
    
    If ws.Name = "Interface" Or ws.Name = "Listes" Then Exit Function
    
    sz = UBound(valuesArray) - LBound(valuesArray) + 1 'size of valuesArray
    
    'pick up data starting with second column
    ar = ws.UsedRange.Columns(2).Resize(, sz).Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(ar, 1)
        checkDuplicate = False
        col = 1
        For j = LBound(valuesArray) To UBound(valuesArray)
            checkDuplicate = ar(i, col) = valuesArray(j) 'match
            If Not checkDuplicate Then Exit For          'no match: stop checking
            col = col + 1                                'next column in sheet array
        Next j
        If checkDuplicate Then Exit Function  'all columns matched - done searching
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried the .Offset as FaneDuru suggested, which is also working :D